# Is there a word for when someone stops being talented?

Tags: single-word-requests

A word for when an artist builds up their ability to paint, but over time their art starts regressing. Or perhaps a child, once magnificent at playing the guitar, begins to pluck the wrong string and slur the notes, eventually becoming mediocre.

Comment: Surely, if a person is really talented their abilities would only start to decline through old age or illness?

Comment: There are [***one-hit wonders***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hit_wonder), which *might* be relevant.

Comment: @KateBunting that's why Olympic champions stop training after their first gold medal in their early 20s...

Comment: Loss of talent? There are limits to talent. Guitarists promising in their youth, to use your example, may eventually reach a plateau and not be able to play like Paco De Lucia, John McLaughlin, or Al Di Meola. Their mistakes are the result of the difficulty of the piece they're playing, not a loss of talent.

Comment: The five stages of an actor's life: 1. Who's Janie Jones? 2. Get me Janie Jones. 3. Get me someone *like* Janie Jones. 4. Get me a *young* Janie Jones. 5. Who's Janie Jones?

Comment: I honestly don't understand why the comments focus on some inability to lose talent. Presumably you could answer all questions on your high school exams without any revision because you were talented in that subject at one point? There are _countless_ examples of artists driving themselves into the ground and being unable to play/draw/paint, as much as there are child prodigies that choose a different path. What does this have to do with the word they are asking for?

Comment: @roganjosh  Because people with talents don't just "stop being talented" Someone who excels doesn't "become mediocre" except through some accident, illness, physical debilitation or personal issue.

Comment: @roganjosh - I understand 'talent' to mean an inborn ability to do something well, not a person's current level of skill.  A person who once played an instrument 'magnificently' might be out of practice or 'rusty', but they don't 'stop being talented'. (I see Tim has just made the same point.)

Comment: That's an interesting distinction. You are both correct in the strict definition, and I am wrong here, but I don't mentally make such a distinction. I have known people pick up programming very quickly but then just drop it and it feels natural to me to say "they were a talented programmer" in that case, implying the talent passed.

Comment: You could say their talent is **atrophying** or that it **atrophied**..

Comment: @KateBunting Pablo Casals famously [claimed to be improving in his old age](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2014/02/12/casals-progress/)! (Whether that's true or not is I suppose a matter of debate.)

Comment: I think this may be more about skill than talent. Talent is generally considered innate, whereas skill is something you acquire through practice. Giving up on practicing will impact skill, but talent doesn't simply disappear unless there's some physical or mental decline.

Comment: Are you asking for a ***noun*** for the peak/apex, or a ***noun*** for the decline/burnout process, or an ***adjective/adjectival phrase/idiom*** for the person after that point ('burned out'/'past their peak'/'declining'/...)?

Comment: @barbecue - Tim and I have already made that point.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan- I didn't mean to imply that old age _always_ leads to a decline in skill, just that it _can_ be a cause.

Comment: "a **child**, once magnificent at playing the guitar, begins to **pluck the wrong string** and **slur the notes**" quickly bring him to a neurologist!!!

Comment: Probably something like "Elonmuskeque".

Comment: It's the 'eventually becoming mediocre' that's the red herring. Most talents can be lost - it's often temporary, in which case, a different word/phrase is applicable. Leading to several of the answers being inappropriate.

Answer (score 27):

They're **washed up**:

> (of a person) no longer effective or successful.
> "a washed-up actress"

(NOAD)

> no longer successful, skillful, popular, or needed
> "*washed-up athletes"
>
> "a washed-up actor*"

(M-W)

It's often used of actors, but can also be used for other professions:

- ["Washed up" artists that you still follow and enjoy](https://rateyourmusic.com/discussion/music/washed-up-artists-that-you-still-follow-and-enjoy/1/)
- [Liz Truss branded 'washed-up' by Chinese state media ahead of Taiwan visit](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/world-news/2023/05/11/liz-truss-branded-washed-up-chinese-media-taiwan/)

Comment: In casual speech nowadays, "washed" is said on it's own, which is nice because that satisfies the OP's single-word requirement.  "Yeah no, I'm washed."

Comment: @AdamBarnes I have never heard that phrase and we're only 20 miles apart, at best!

Comment: @roganjosh spooky that you're stalkin' me but you do you.  It's likely we don't share the same interests - watch NiceWigg whiff an entire magazine on someone in APEX Legends and you'll hear him say it.

Comment: @AdamBarnes I mean, it's a simple case of just clicking your name once and seeing that you're from Bury on your profile... stalking is a pretty strong term for that.

Comment: Weird, I wonder when I wrote that, it's been incorrect for a long time.  Regardless, hope you're having a good time up North!

Answer (score 18):

You could say that the person **lost their edge**. Here is the *[Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cambridge_Dictionary_of_American_Idioms/ytJNRDL0zDgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=lost%20edge%20slang&pg=PA109&printsec=frontcover)*:

> "lose your edge" - to no longer have the determination or skills that made you successful in the past. "Long ago, Foster figured out you could act like a gentleman and still not lose your edge."

You can switch out the possessive pronoun as you need to - lose his edge, lost our edge:

> DeAndre Hopkins: Assessing Patriots' fit - has star receiver lost his edge? ([A to Z Sports article](https://atozsports.com/new-england/patriots-deandre-hopkins-assessing-regression-has-the-star-receiver-lost-his-edge/))

Comment: Similarly, "lost your mojo", though this seems to be a sillier variant. The comedy "Austin Powers" centres around this expression, and is perhaps why it seems a bit more silly to me. 
https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lose+your+mojo

Answer (score 17):

**[Has-been](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/has-been)** - Cambridge Dictionary

> a person who in the past was famous, important, admired, or good at something, but is no longer any of these

You could say:

> That person is a has-been artist.

This is a bit tricky because it could imply that the times simply moved on; their skill hasn't diminished, but it becomes outdated in the current era. At the same time, it can imply that the person just lost their talent either through lack of practice or, sometimes, going astray i.e. alcoholism or something.

Answer (score 11):

This is an expression rather than a single word, but it's very commonly used. Using the 'up = good' metaphor, for someone who is **past their best** (this is obviously time- but also almost always age-related)  in one or more areas, they are often said to be **over the hill**.

> *over the hill* [phrase of *hill*] [informal]:
>
> old and past one's best.
>
> - *a once famous ballerina, now over the hill*

[[Oxford Languages, courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=over+the+hill+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=over+the+hill+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i67i650j0i512l2j0i22i30l3j0i15i22i30l3.3260134103j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

Another common expression involves semi-referential (not overtly specified, but a logical referent easily retrieved) 'it':

> **lose it**  ...
> 2. To lose an ability, skill, or quality that one previously had.
>
> - *I used to be so much better at the guitar, but I feel like I'm losing it.*
> - *She used to turn heads wherever she went, but I think she's lost it a little as she's aged.*

[[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lose+it)]

Obviously, context is needed to force this sense of 'lose it'.

Comment: Slightly different version **past their prime**

Comment: In American English, this more commonly means someone is over the age of 40.

Comment: Someone struggles up the hill gaining talent, experience and fans, they reach their summit and then pass out of sight as they begin the passage down the hill. You know that when at the grocery checkout a tabloid headline is "whatever happened to ...".

Answer (score 10):

**Lose one's touch** is another idiom that fits. Note that, it differs from the idiom *lose touch*.

> To no longer be skilled in doing something. In this usage, a possessive pronoun is used between "lose" and "touch."
>
> *He used to be one of the league's elite shooters, but it seems like he's lost his touch.*
>
> <sub>lose one's touch. (n.d.) Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. (2015). Retrieved July 22 2023 from https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lose+one%27s+touch</sub>

Answer (score 7):

The point in time would be generally identified as "burnout".

Most other answers seem to be addressing the post-burnout state, hence "past their prime" etc.

Comment: Isn't burnout often a temporary state, so that after a period of rest and rejuvenation, the artist can return to greatness? I understood the question to be looking for a more permanent loss.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. "The light that burns twice as bright burns half as long- and you have burned so very, very brightly, Roy."

Comment: This may imply that the individual no longer *enjoys* the activity, rather than that they're no longer *good* at it. Many talented actors/musicians have burned out due to the pressures of fame and stepped away from their craft, but that doesn't mean they are no longer talented. It means they can't bring themselves to apply their talent like they once did. You won't see the talent of a burned out individual, but that's often because they choose not to exercise it, not because they don't have it anymore.

Comment: It's also worth clarifying that burnout is a very modern understanding of what's actually going on.  It's less a figure of speech like the others and more of a diagnosis.  Not a flaw but worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 5):

This artist or guitarist is **spent**, an expression that covers a variety of contexts.

From Merriam-Webster:

> 1a : used up : CONSUMED
> b : exhausted of active or required components or qualities often for a particular purpose:
> *spent nuclear fuel*
> 2 : drained of energy or effectiveness : EXHAUSTED
> 3 : exhausted of spawn or sperm:  *spent fishes*

Comment: This was going to be my suggestion as well. "Spent" is the best single word answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

A term that started with golf and has spread to other endeavors involving motor control is "having the yips". This is specific to motor skills like golf or playing the guitar, and it implies that the loss of skill is sudden and hoped to be temporary. So it may not be a good fit. But it might match the case of the guitarist.

Answer (score 3):

Someone who seems very promising at first, but turns out to be less than expected and a disappointment, can be called **just a flash in the pan**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a word that describes the person who stops being talented but an artist sometimes develops an artist's block.  He or she still has the innate talent but, for whatever reason, does not feel inspired to continue his or her art, or at least not at the same level as before.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

A phrase that has become more current in the last few decades with food labelling is **to be past your sell-by date**.

> A date printed on a product such as food after which it should not be sold 
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sell-by-date).

Also use by, or best before.

Thanks to Edwin Ashworth for finding these more relevant metaphorical uses in [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/past-your-sell-by-date)

> past your sell-by date
>
> no longer useful, successful, or relevant
>
> > This type of TV programme is well past its sell-by date.
>
> > So, if you're feeling past your sell-by date, remember: 60 is the age of reinvention, and here is how you do it.
> > Times, Sunday Times (2007)
>
> > Having something new and worthwhile to turn to makes it much easier to avoid clinging to a job past your sell-by date.
> > Times, Sunday Times (2013)

Comment: I've never heard this describing people. It would be helpful to have examples of it in use.

Comment: Collins gives the broadened (metaphorical) usage for both say ideas, and people.

Answer (score 1):

The word that describes this phenomenon is "regression." Regression refers to a decline or return to a less developed or less skilled state. In the context of an artist or a child's abilities, it means that they once reached a higher level of skill or proficiency but have now started to decline or lose some of their previous abilities, resulting in a lower standard of performance or output.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"He's lost his edge" can be used in that context (Free Dictionary). "Past it" is a phrase that can be used for someone who has become too old to still pursue their profession as it requires youthful vigor or flexibility, such as a ballet dancer or athlete (Merriam-Webster Dictionary).

A person has "peaked" if they reached the apex of their abilities and are starting to go downhill. (I was unable to find a source for this but it's common parlance.) "They've gone downhill" can work in the context of your question (Cambridge Dictionary), as can "past her/his/their prime" in the context of singing, athletics, rather than beauty or age (Cambridge Dictionary).

I agree with [Neil_UK](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/610441/191178) who indicated that "past your sell-by date" is a contemporary rough equivalent to "past your prime" (Collins Dictionary). "Flash in the pan" can refer to someone who briefly exhibited talent but was unable to sustain their ability (Cambridge Dictionary).

Comment: Do note that phrases like "the person above" should be avoided because the order of answers changes. Right now you're above the person you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to their playing, you could say it has **Jumped the shark** referring to "a pejorative that is used to argue that a creative work or entity has reached a point in which it has exhausted its core intent and is introducing new ideas that are discordant with, or an over-exaggeration of, its original purpose." (Wikipedia)

Since your example mentioned a child, you could say they have **peaked early**, since the remainder of their playing career will be a long decline.

Comment: "Jumped the shark" tends to be applied to the creative work (especially TV shows) rather than the creators.